# Django Soak Testing Bulk Request at once

Tags: django, django-orm, django-testing

I want to test whether Django can handle heavy load requests at once continuously. How to conduct this scenario? using tests?.

Eg:

```
300 Read requests 
300 Write requests
within 1 sec.
```

You can take any basic ORM query like

```
User.objects.get(id=`some id)
```

for 1 request and take this as 300 different read requests.
Same for write requests as well but change any field of your choice.
Later check if that works for at-least 10 sec. 
You can think of this scenario as multiple concurrent users using the Django app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution myself to use [locust](https://locust.io/) But I'll still wait for someone to give a better answer before accepting my own answer.
There is also a paid site for testing Django - [gatling](https://gatling.io/)